# Change Color on discord.js embed text

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to change the color of text for certain sections of a discord.js embed?

````
  .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('~__Command Hewp__~')
  .addFields(
    { name: `**${prefix + 'help'}**`, value: `Usage: ${prefix + 'help'}` },
    { name: `${prefix + 'purge'}`, value: `Usage: ${prefix + 'purge'} <# of Messages, max 100>` },
    { name: `${prefix + 'kick'}`, value: `Usage: ${prefix + 'kick'} <target user>` },
    { name: `${prefix + 'ban'}`, value: `Usage: ${prefix + 'ban'} <target user>` },
     );
     message.channel.send(help)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Discord does not support changing the color of text. The only option is to use [code blocks](https://gist.github.com/Almeeida/41a664d8d5f3a8855591c2f1e0e07b19) in `field.value`, but it doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the response text message by formatting it in certain ways.

Here's the detailed breakdown of the formats

````
```arm
Orange
```

```fix
Yellow
```

```yaml
Cyan
```

```md
# Blue
```

```diff
- This is red
```

```
Grey
```
````

Remember to use `-` to start the text in `diff` and `#` for `md`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29378237)

Comment: Good point. Let me update my answer with more information.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it basically creates code blocks with colored text.